# Android - Call style.xml with onclick

Tags: android

I have this code

```
<style name="large">
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
</style>
```

My layout

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_s"
    android:text="@string/button_small" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_l"
    android:text="@string/button_large" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Hello World" />
```

I want when i click button large, it call style **large** . Please help me!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do when clicking `button_l`?

Comment: when i click button_l so <style name="large">
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
</style> will be call, and change textview size to 20dp

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_l);
final TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(ActivityName.this, R.style.large);
        } else {
            textViewTitle.setTextAppearance(R.style.large);
        }
    }
});
```